# ProfileView plot not showing when running Julia Code

Tags: julia, profiling, profiler

I wanted to profile my code in Julia and I installed the package "ProfileView.jl". However, when I run the code the windows is popping for a second and closing immediately.

I have run the script from VS Code and also from the terminal. The code I am profiling is:

```
using ProfileView
@profview Mesh,MatPointData, AnalysisConstants = setupfunc(T)
```

Comment: It's impossible to tell what's wrong from this. Maybe start with `Pkg.add("Gtk"); Pkg.test("Gtk")` and see if the tests pass on your system.

Comment: I have added GTK and all the test passed, still the behaviour hasn't changed. Is it because the program is ending after the profview line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, you should run ProfileView interactively in a REPL, not as part of a script. If you're using VSCode, you want to start the Julia REPL (Ctrl-Shift-P and then `Julia: Start REPL`); from the terminal, you want to run an interactive session, i.e., `$ julia` and not `$ julia somescript.jl`.

If you simply must use a script (again, not recommended because you'll lose access to some nice interactive functionality in ProfileView), see https://juliagraphics.github.io/Gtk.jl/latest/manual/nonreplusage/.